# Что надо надо дописать к запросу что бы получить количество определеных значений?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Вот таким запросом

```
SELECT "bonus", (nlevel(tree_path) - nlevel('2.383')) as nl,count(nl)
FROM "user" 
INNER JOIN "user_bonus_item" 
ON user_id_from = "user".id 
WHERE ("tree_path" ~ '2.383.*{0,5}')
AND user_id_to = user_id_from 
AND ("user_bonus_item"."mounth_bonus" = '9:2017') 
AND ("bonus" > 50) 
ORDER BY "nl";
```

получаю

```
bonus  | nl 
--------+----
 305.00 |  0
  52.00 |  1
  52.00 |  1
  51.00 |  1
  52.00 | 2
   60.00| 3
```

подскажите что мне надо ещё дописать к запросу что бы получить количество `nl` которые равны `1`

Comment: не очень понятно, какой результат вы хотите. Что должно быть для тех `nl`, которые не равны 1 ?. Добавьте, пожалуйста, ожидаемый результат в вопрос

Comment: в том же датасете или отдельно?

Comment: добавить в where условие, которое оставит только нужные записи и получить count(1) _вместо_ всех остальных колонок